# Angular - Compiling linked files

Tags: angular, typescript

Im creating an external Django's module that has its own files for frontend management (a couple of models and a services).

My idea was link these files inside the frontend folder with **LN -S** command.
The other frontend files seems to accept the linked files so no IDE errors is raise.

Unfortunally, compile doesn't works. Its seems it is aware the files are not really there.

The error says:

```
ERROR in /usr/local/src/<external_path>/models/MyExternalModel.ts
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js):
Error: /usr/local/src/<external_path>/models/MyExternalModel.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
```

Is there a way to allow compiling linked files?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, see the last line of the error..

Comment: I know the error. I need a solution. The files are in the path with others but they are symbolic link and not the real ones.

Comment: So you have added those additional files to either the include or the files section of tsconfig..? And you’re still getting this error?